# Is there a purpose to using app.set() and app.get()?

Tags: javascript, express

Can I just hard code it in:

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('Server|Port: ', app.get('port'));
});
```

instead do this, it is a bit more readable

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;      
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server|Port: ', port);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.set()` and `app.get()` are just ways of storing custom properties in the `app` object without any chance of conflicting with built-in properties on the object.  So, you can use them for any `app` level storage you want.

You are free to store the `port` you choose either with:

```
app.set(port, process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

and then retrieve it with

```
app.get('port')
```

or you can use your other option:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

Either will work just fine.  Which to use is entirely a personal coding choice.  Personally, I would use the `const port = xxxx` because the port is not something that is generally needed by other code after the server has been started.

> Is there a purpose to using app.set() and app.get()?

The main benefit of `app.get()` is that any code that has the `app` object can get access to that property so it's a convenient way to store app-level data where a lot of your code (like all your route handlers) has easy access to it even if they're spread into lots of other modules.  In the case of the port number, that is generally not something that lots of other code needs access to, so I'd personally just put it in a local variable and use it there.

Comment: this is a great answer, but can you give me one example of app level data.  I'm processing in my express skills but have not had the need for app level data yet.

Comment: @rebeccakan - Some examples might be app level state such as debug flags, logging level, application-level cache, database reference, socket.io reference, api keys for external services, etc...

Comment: I have most of those things compartmentalized to a single file.  Maybe as my app gets more complex I will find a use for it.